# When creating a Fortran 90 shared library, how can arrange it so that I can access the modules the library uses?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am creating a Fortran 90 shared library and its Python bindings. I need to adjust it so that the user will have access to the shared library's modules when using both Fortran and Python.

Python part is easy, I will create signature files and use `f2py`. Then the modules will be universally accessible.

However the user will need to access the modules also in Fortran. For this, the user will need the `.mod` files.

- I am reluctant to distribute the `.mod` files and install with the library because it's unorthodox.
- I also don't want to make the user copy the files that define the modules into their own project every time they need to access one.

It is also useful to say that I am using `NumPy`'s build system which utilizes Python. Specifically `numpy.distutils`.

So here is my solution:

- I will define the modules inside header files, one header file for each module.
- During the compilation of the library itself, for each header file `foo.h`, there will be a corresponding `foo.90` in `src/modules` containing a single line:

```
include  'foo.h'
```

This way, the library will have access to the modules.

- For the user, when using the library, if the user wants to access the module `foo` the user will include the line

```
include 'foo.h'
```

once, in any file they want. This way `.mod` files will be generated in user's own directory, and the project would be compiled, giving the user access to those parts of memory the modules reside in.

Does this seem reasonable? Is there any other way you know that is better and less hacky (that does not involve the distribution of the `.mod` files)?

Comment: If you distribute the Fortran code itself users can create their own .mod files by compiling the code. You don't want to distribute the code?

Comment: @Fortranner I will distribute it, but according to my design, the user should not have to recompile library's files inside the project, or make references to binaries other than the shared library, like the ``mod`` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely don't want to distribute the .mod files because they change with compiler and even compiler version.  Since you are willing to distribute the source code, I think the easiest solution is to place your code into some particular directory and provide the user with instructions to include `use XYZ` in their code and instructions on how to compile that module with their code, perhaps providing a sample Make or command file.  If you want to minimize the code that they compile, you could write a special module with interfaces describing your procedures.  That approach creates a maintenance burden of maintaining the interfaces to be consistent with the procedures.   Of course, if you were to alter the arguments of a procedure, it would impact the code of your users, so maybe you will never do that.

Comment: That was what I described and had in mind. Changing the api's would not cause much of a trouble for the user, though, since the api consists of some 3-4 subroutines that the user has to redefine, to use the library with their own program. And they won't change. Any consistent change made outside of that scope has virtually no chance of affecting the user and their program. So I am taking this answer as a confirmation of what I had in mind, and proceeding accordingly.

Comment: It becomes easier if the user only needs access to a small number of subroutines.  You can either create a special module with interfaces for just those subroutines or you could divide your module into two, one with the routines that the user needs to directly call, which they would could compile to obtain the module file, and another with the library routines that are only indirectly called by the user and for which they don't need the module information.